# Method requires more than one argument?

Tags: c++, methods, arguments, signature

So, I can't compile my code like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> split = split("A String Blah");
```

with this method signature:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s)
```

because it says it requires more than one argument.  Why isn't just a string enough?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error 1 error C2660: 'split' : function does not take 1 arguments c:\users\aidan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\mathhelper\mathhelper\mathhelper.cpp 59 1 MathHelper

Comment: is the `split` you think you are calling from the MathHelper library?

Comment: Did you create a function prototype _before_ you attempted to call the function?

Comment: The problem was I forgot to update the prototype when I updated the method signature.  Thanks @JoachimPileborg!

Comment: It's not so much "more than one argument" as "not exactly one argument."

Answer (score 6):

When you have this line:

```
std::vector<std::string> split = split("A String Blah");
```

The C++ compiler thinks that the `split` referred to in the right-hand side is the same `split` declared on the left-hand side.  As a result, it's giving you an error because, indeed, a `std::vector<std::string>` is not a function taking one argument.

To fix this, consider renaming the variable:

```
std::vector<std::string> theSplit = split("A String Blah");
```

Hope this helps!